# APC not being utilised in Gentoo/Apache 2.2

Tags: apache-2.2, alternative-php-cache

I've installed APC on my Gentoo LAMP server (Apache 2.2, PHP 5.2.13) and it's running fine (I see it in phpinfo()), but it's not actually doing any caching. Looking at apc.php, I can see that only 1.7% of its memory allocation is being used, which is one file of ~430kb. I'm running a CMS on the server (concrete5) which has hundreds of PHP files, so I'd expect cache utilisation to be a lot higher. Obviously it's being ignored, for some reason.

The relevant settings in php.ini are:

```
[apc]
apc.enabled = 1
apc.shm_size = 32
```

Other than that it's vanilla, as far as I know.

If it helps, here's the output of httpd -M:

```
Loaded Modules:
 core_module (static)
 authn_file_module (static)
 authn_default_module (static)
 authz_host_module (static)
 authz_groupfile_module (static)
 authz_user_module (static)
 authz_default_module (static)
 auth_basic_module (static)
 include_module (static)
 filter_module (static)
 deflate_module (static)
 log_config_module (static)
 env_module (static)
 expires_module (static)
 headers_module (static)
 setenvif_module (static)
 version_module (static)
 ssl_module (static)
 mpm_prefork_module (static)
 http_module (static)
 mime_module (static)
 status_module (static)
 autoindex_module (static)
 asis_module (static)
 info_module (static)
 suexec_module (static)
 cgi_module (static)
 negotiation_module (static)
 dir_module (static)
 actions_module (static)
 userdir_module (static)
 alias_module (static)
 rewrite_module (static)
 so_module (static)
 suphp_module (shared)
Syntax OK
```

and php -m:

```
[PHP Modules]
bcmath
calendar
ctype
curl
db
dbase
domxml
exif
ftp
gd
gettext
iconv
imap
mbstring
mcrypt
mime_magic
mysql
openssl
overload
pcre
posix
session
standard
sysvsem
sysvshm
tokenizer
xml
xslt
zlib

[Zend Modules]
```

Any ideas would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Have you added extension=apc.so somewhere in php.ini? This is exactly the most common error when trying to configure APC: not loading it.

Comment: Yep it's in there. It's definitely running, because I can see it in phpinfo() and when I run apc.php (which comes with the package) it shows its stats.

Comment: FWIW: apc doesn't show up in your `php -m`; You must have different php.ini's for apache and cli?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure APC setting `apc.cache_by_default = 1`; Otherwise nothing will get opcode cached, only variables manually requested by code.